# How to use .find() with data we have using .get()?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am having trouble using .find() as in console it says .find is not a function.

My code looks like:

```
$.get('/est.html', function(data) {
$.each(['rental', 'deposit', 'data', 'build'], function(i, key) {
    $('#lot-' + key).html(data.find('#est-' + key));
});
}, 'html');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find` is supposed to work on a jQuery object/selector. So wrap it with `$`

```
 $('#lot-' + key).html($(data).find('#est-' + key));
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to make it a jquery object by wrapping with $():

```
$(data).find('..');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#lot-' + key).html(data.find('#est-' + key));
```

should be

```
 $('#lot-' + key).html($(data).find('#est-' + key));
```